# Converting a list of mutations to number

Tags: r, reshape

I have a list of samples and the name of mutations happen in each sample in a second column. For a given sample, there may be more than one mutation like below

[image]

In R, how I can convert it into a data frame with sample label in one column and then the absolute number of mutations per sample in a second column?

Comment: Look for question about "summarize by group", where your summary statistics is likely `length`. This can be done with `aggregate`, `tapply`, `dplyr::group_by`/`summarize`, etc.

Comment: `df %>% count(Tumor_Sample_Barcode)` using `dplyr`.